# Insert record in table with restriction

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I use sql server and a table like this:

```
MyTbale(ID int IDENTITY, Type Char(1), ParentId int)
```

I want to restrict my users that insert the first record with some ParentId with `Type = 'O'`, and can insert other record with some parentId with each Type. In other word if user want to insert a record with ParentId=10 must set Type = 'O' and after this, can Insert each type with ParentId = 10.

Sample Data:

```
Id     Type  ParentId
1      O     10
2      I     10
3      I     10
4      M     10
5      N     10
6      O     12
7      M     12
8      I     12
```

What's the best solution for this problem? ( I think that I can use constraint with UDF and trigger for this purpose).

**EDIT**

by following format I can add check constraint:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[f](@Id INT, @Date DATE) RETURNS BIT 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @R BIT = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Date FROM MyTable WHERE Date=@Date AND Id!=@Id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    RETURN @R
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_test] CHECK  (([dbo].[F]([Id],[Date])=(0)))
```

and by following query I can add trigger for check data:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_MyTable ON dbo.MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM Inserted i
              LEFT JOIN MyTable t ON t.ParentId = i.ParentId AND t.Type = 'O'
              WHERE i.Type <> 'O'
                    AND t.Id IS NULL) BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Type must be equal to O in first row',16,1)
    END
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Type,ParentId)
    SELECT Type, ParentId
    FROM Inserted
END
```

Comment: You definitely can't use `check constraint` for this. I think `trigger` would be best choice.

Comment: @Rahul. I edit my question. I can use constraint and trigger, but looked for best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The INSTEAD OF TRIGGER would be the way to go. Also, if you don't need the error information returned, you might gain some performance with this slightly revised suggestion:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_MyTable ON dbo.MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Type,ParentId)
    SELECT Type, ParentId
    FROM Inserted
    LEFT JOIN MyTable t ON t.ParentId = i.ParentId AND t.Type = 'O'
              WHERE i.Type <> 'O'
                    AND t.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: Your condition is wrong you must use `i.Type = 'O' or t.Id is not null`.